# How to make two different code generate random numbers but they are different?

Tags: random, numbers, generated

Let's say I have a code following under

```
a = 4
b = random.sample(range(1,14), (a))
```

Now if I print this, this would give me random 4 numbers in range 1~13 and let's say it is [3, 7, 1, 11]

However, I want to add another line under that code which will generate additional
3 different numbers in range 1~13 that the first code did not generate.
e.g [4, 9, 13]

How should I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `c = random.sample(range(1,14), 3)`

Comment: No I don't want the second code to generate numbers that were already generated by the first code.

Comment: How about you ran the random.sample with 7 (4+3) instead of separately, and the split result in two? I dont really have any experience on this - just a suggestion

Comment: The purpose of asking this question is because I want to make different use for each b and c.  Assuming b = the 1st code and c = the 2nd code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
a = 4
b = random.sample(range(1,14), (a))
c = random.sample([x for x in range(1,14) if x not in b], (a))
```

Comment: I love this one more! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers_left = set(range(1, 14)).difference(set(b))
c = random.sample(numbers_left, 3)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, sorry if I want to assign one more group 'd' (with using the same rule) how should I write the code?